# SPF for site+mail server using single VPS

Tags: email, vps, spf

Spent too much time to figure out how to configure spf record in my case:

```
domain: example.org x.x.x.x (using cloudflare y.y.y.y)
mx: mail.example.org x.x.x.x (cf proxy disabled)
vps: vps.company.com x.x.x.x

hostname: vps.company.com
smtp hello: vps.company.com
smtp from: <user>@vps.company.com
```

My last spf entry: "v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x a mx -all" and it fails...

How this should be handled in proper way? What spf entry should be in my case?

edit:
Here is mail headers sent from site example.org by sendmail:

```
Authentication-Results: mxs.mail.ru; spf=none () smtp.mailfrom=user@vps.company.com smtp.helo=vps.company.com
Received-SPF: none
Received: from [x.x.x.x] (port=35646 helo=vps.company.com)
    by mx188.mail.ru with esmtp (envelope-from <user@vps.company.com>)
    for user@mail.ru; Sun, 18 Jan 2015 11:01:33 +0300
Received: by vps.company.com (Postfix, from userid 100)
    id <value>; Sun, 18 Jan 2015 15:01:30 +0300
To: user@mail.ru
From: <admin@example.org>
Reply-To: <admin@example.org>
Sender: <admin@example.org>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your record should be: `"v=spf1 mx:mail.example.org -all"`

You don't need ip4 or a just to allow mail.example.org to mail on behalf of vps.company.com. Also, check out http://www.spfwizard.com/ and Port 25 has a great service for helping troubleshoot spf and dkim issues http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/ it will reply to your test message with a useful breakdown of how it interprets the policy and why it rejected the message.

Comment: Can you plz explain, why "v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x -all" fails then? I still didnt get why mx will not fail over ip4.

Comment: Specifying mx:mailserver.example.com is generally incorrect, unless you truly want SPF validation to look up all the hosts that accept mail for the "mailserver.example.com" domain. (Usually, there will not be any such hosts, because "mailserver.example.com" is itself a host, not a domain.) This will not show up as a syntax error, however, it will simply not match anything. (c) openspf.org

Comment: sorry @kill2kill I assumed from your question that you were trying to authorize mailserver.example.com to deliver for vps.company.com - it really should be so simple and there's no reason ip4 wouldn't work. Fyi all these mechanisms work on the "purported responsible address" which is typically the envelope-from, the address actually used in the 'mail from' command

Comment: hey, check out my answer - already tried this solution and it works perfect. Sry for misunderstood question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, seems like I got wheres the problem: dunno why but I thought, that spf record checked for domain specified in "from" sections, like qwerty@domain.com, poor me =)

To solve my problem:

1. Add A record - vps.example.org -> x.x.x.x
2. Change PTR record - x.x.x.x -> vps.example.org
3. Change SPF/TXT record - "v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x -all"
4. Change MX record to target vps.example.org

Obviously you need to change (in my case, cuz I sent mails with php mail() function) sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f user@example.org, after that, postfix's settings should be adjusted too: myhostname = vps.example.org, mydomain = example.org (mydestination - based on your configuration).

Final spf record: "v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x -all"

Also - [Use "mx" with domain names, not mailserver names](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes)